# Internet cuts out and cannot reconnect, DHCP not enabled

Tags: windows-7, internet, vpn, dhcp

Sometimes the internet cuts out and then when I try to reestablish a connection it gives me limited connectivity where I can't access anything. The network problem diagnostic tool can repair the problem and it says "DHCP is not enabled for local area connections". How can I keep DHCP enabled and why does it turn off? I have a VPN which is set to kill all internet activity if the VPN fails.